# Running local Java applet that accesses the local file system on Safari

Tags: java, macos, safari, applet, osx-lion

I am unable to save a file to the local file system using the TiddlySaver.jar applet under MacOSX 10.7.5 and Safari 6.0.2. 
http://tiddlywiki.com/

Supposedly in Safari 6.0 there is a menu item under "Develop" called "Disable Local File Restrictions", but I do not see it in Safari 6.0.2.  Perhaps there is another way to disable the restrictions that I am unaware of?

Comment: *" Perhaps there is another way to disable the restrictions"* Possibly a) Digitally sign the Jar ..or b) Use the JNLP API services to access the local file-system.

Comment: I verified that the jar already is signed using jarsigner -verify.  I'll look into the JNLP API as an alternative option, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The menu item you're thinking of disabled restrictions on Javascript. It does not affect Java applets.

Your issues are more likely to be because [Apple temporarily blacklisted versions of the Java plugin prior to Java 7 update 11 from loading at all](http://9to5mac.com/2013/01/11/apple-blocks-java-7-mac-plugin-in-os-x-following-discovered-security-vulnerability/). (Mozilla took similar measures for Firefox.) Download and install Java 7 update 11 to make it start working again.

Comment: Additional info.  It is currently the same with the Windows based JRE 1.7.0_09 & 1.7.0_11 Oracle versions.  Specifically, the warning I see when trying to load an applet in FF is *"This plugin has security vulnerabilities.  Click here to activate the Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U plugin."*  Hopefully that update for the affected JREs (including presumably *nix) will be forthcoming 'real soon now'.

Comment: Yep, Mozilla blacklisted the plugin from Firefox as well. (It's kind of a big deal. Widespread exploits.) The update showed up around 6 hours ago; you can download Java 7 update 11 now from: http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Comment: Oddly (just even rebooted to check again) though I'd installed the 11 update as soon as I'd seen the problem, I'm still getting the message.  Console output `Java Plug-in 10.5.1.255
Using JRE version 1.7.0_11-b21 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = ..`.  Presumably it is being triggered by `Java Plug-in` version.  Nice to see it is enabled again on Mac so soon (getting back to the specific question/problem).  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yep, even with FF **18.0.1**, I get the _"this plugin has security vulnerabilities"_ warning when trying to run a signed applet.  The Java Console tells me I'm running `Java Plug-in 10.11.2.21 Using JRE version **1.7.0_11-b21** Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM`.  It's very frustrating, especially when I'm the author of the applet and the digital signature process was painful to go through!